# iOS: filepath of xml doc is correct (and xml displays in browser) but NSData pulled from doc comes up as null

Tags: ios, xml, nsdata, filepath

Hi my code for pulling XML from a XML doc placed on a web server suddenly appears to have broken...

```
    NSString *filePath = [userDefaults objectForKey:kStaticContentFilePath];
    NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData
                                                           options:0 error:&error];
```

In the debugger I see that filePath is correctly set as "http://mydevserver.com/html/static_content.xml" (value of kStaticContentFilePath)

I see a nice dump of xml in a browser when I access that URL.

However, xmlData in debugger shows up as set to nil

And the error var in debugger gets set to "Error Domain=com.google.GDataXML Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GDataXML error -1.)"

Any advise would be most appreciated! Need to get this resolved over the next 3 hours!! :-)

Comment: This, quite strangely fixed itself (before the deadline ... phew :-) The only thing I can think of is it was caused perhaps by a connection or server error (mysteriously the connection worked in a browser and not when made via the initWithContentsOfURL call)